# Run Powershell script from file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a Powershell script from a file in a Jenkins pipeline.

I have read [this](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/) which shows how to run powershell scripts that are entered into the pipeline, but I can't get a script to run from a file.

I have tried:

```
powershell returnStatus: true, script: '-File build.ps1'
```

and various combinations but can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Figured it out soon after, the line should have read

```
powershell returnStatus: true, script: '.\\build.ps1'
```

Comment: how would one go about passing arguments to their PS script this way?

Comment: I don't think you should be passing in arguments to the script from the pipeline, but accessing variables through environment variables in the script

Comment: how do you set environment variables from Jenkins tp be used by PowerShell? @bic

Comment: @bic - all Jenkins env vars in scope at the time powershell is invoked are available in the powershell scope, also as env vars. This includes Jenkins default env vars like `BUILD_NUMBER` etc, but also anything you set in the env prior to that point. Keep in mind the env var scoping rules I get into in [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538778/556078).

Answer (score 3):

@bic's answer works great, and it helped me a lot. If you need to pass variables in and you don't want to use environment vars *inside* the script, the best way I've found is a two-liner (declarative syntax):

```
writeFile file: 'tempFile.ps1', text: "${libraryResource 'psScript1.ps1'}"
powershell './tempFile.ps1 -someArg $env:someArg'
```

So you're writing a temp file with the content of the script to the local dir. Then you're calling the script directly with `powershell`, and injecting the vars in the call.

I agree it's more convenient to use environment vars in your scripts. There are a few patterns you have to keep in mind:

1. Env vars set in the top-level `environment` block can't be changed during the run. (At least that is my experience.)
2. Env vars can **only** be Strings. There are tricks you can play to get maps to work, but they're tricks.
3. If you want to set an env var that's changeable throughout the pipeline's scope, you have to do it in a `script` block in a step. I usually set them all up in my `('init')` stage. You should then be able to use and modify these vars anywhere in the pipe - *and* any sub-scripts that are spawned off of it. If you have a lot of env vars, i'd recommend shunting them off to an external groovy library.

   ```
   pipeline {
      ...
      stage('init') {
        steps {
          script {
            env.myVariable = 'some value'
          }
        }
      }
     ...
   ```
4. You can also set env vars scoped only to that stage. In my experience, these are *not* evaluated before entering the actual steps block - ie, they will not be set during `when` condition evaluations. Again, just my experience, i might be wrong.

   ```
   stage('A') {
     environment {
       stageEnvVar = 'another value'
     }
     steps {
       ...
     }
   }
   ```

This is the best reference I've found on Jenkins env vars: https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/