# I would like to execute my powershell script in Jenkins and show results OK/NOK

Tags: powershell, jenkins-groovy

I would like to execute my powershell scripts. To do this I've written a basic jenkinsfile. However, Jenkins constantly complains about either a unexpected '\' character or it simply says that the path I've given is not the OK. Or that the cmdlet is not properly used.

I've tried:

```
call '& "C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\CommandLineConversieALLtestcases.ps1"'
```

```
powershell '& "C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\PSscript\KopieerToolUitvoerVorigeTestrun.ps1"'
```

```
powershell '& C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\PSscript\KopieerToolUitvoerVorigeTestrun.ps1
                            & C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\PSscript\KopieerConfig-test.ps1
                            & C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\PSscript\VerwijderResultaten.ps1'
```

```
call 'C:\\WSEB\\Conversietool\\UT\\ConversieToolTestcases\\CommandLineConversieDSO.ps1'
```

```
powershell 'C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\CommandLineConversieALLtestcases.ps1'
```

I'm at a loss here. I would like Jenkins to simply tell me if the tests were OK/NOK (warnings/errors etc). The powershell files are located in `C:\WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases`

Comment: Could it be that you need to escape the ```\``` slash? So replace all backslashes with two backslashes

Comment: I've tried this aswell @Mathias.

Comment: `powershell.exe -File "C:\WSEB\Co...stcases.ps1"`. That should return the exit code of the script to Jenkins. What exit code the script returns depends on what you're doing inside the script.

Comment: I would then get a ```WorkflowScript: 64: expecting '}', found 'C:\SVN_WSEB\Conversietool\UT\ConversieToolTestcases\CommandLineConversieALLtestcases.ps1' @ line 64, column 26.
       powershell.exe -File "C:\\SVN_WSEB\\Conversietool\\UT\\ConversieToolTestcases\\CommandLineConversieALLtestcases.ps1"```

Why is this? The brackets closing the method seem OK.

Comment: This is my code right now:

```stage('Powershell scripts') 
  {
   steps 
   {
    powershell.exe -File "C:\\SVN_WSEB\\Conversietool\\UT\\ConversieToolTestcases\\CommandLineConversieALLtestcases.ps1"
   }
  }```

Comment: Im using the following now for testing:

```{
            stage('compiling, test, packaging') 
            {
                bat label: '', script: 'mvn clean package'
                powershell.exe -File "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\example.ps1"
            }```

But for some reason it keeps failing because jenkins still doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. You can execute a powershell script file with the following:

`powershell returnStatus: true, script: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\example.ps1'`

Credits to: bic ([Run Powershell script from file in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726756/run-powershell-script-from-file-in-jenkins-pipeline))