# Passing parameters down a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot get Jenkins to pass a string Parameter down the pipeline.

When I run the pipeline, I input the string value for `$ServiceName` and the job continues but it doesn't pass this param to the first job in the pipe (NEWSERVICE - Add New). In the jenkins file in the 'build' stage I've tried `params.ServiceName`, `$params.ServiceName`, `env.ServiceName`, `$env.ServiceName`, `$env:ServiceName`. No luck.

I need to pass the param to a Powershell build process in the NEWSERVICE job (which currently just echos the Param with `$env:ServiceName` - but it's always empty) Any help would be vastly appreciated.

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
    parameters{
        string(name:  'ServiceName',
            defaultValue: '',
            description: '',)
    }
    stages {                

        stage('Add new Service'){
            steps {

                build(job: "NEWSERVICE - Add New", parameters: [string(name: 'ServiceName', value: params.ServiceName)])

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pipeline you need to pass string parameters like this:

```
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ServiceName', value: ServiceName]
        ],
```

Refer this to understand different type of variable passing while calling a job from Jenkinsfile.
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a Jenkins env var in a powershell script - which i do all the time! - the env var has to be set up as such in Jenkins first. In other words,
`env.myVar` in a Jenkins context will be visible as `$env:myVar` in a PowerShell context. But you need to set it as an env var, *local* Jenkins variables won't be visible to a child script (unless passed in as a parameter). I have a detailed writeup here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538778/556078